# export an object to excel and download it in ionic angular 14

Tags: angular, ionic5

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exporttoexcel',
  templateUrl: 'exporttoexcel.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['exporttoexcel.page.scss'],
})
export class ExportToExcelPage {

  data:any = [];

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.data = [{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }];
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    
  }

  ExportToExcel(){
    this.getExcelReport()
  }

  async getExcelReport() {
      var filename = "test";
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.data);
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, filename);
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename + '.xlsx');
    }

}
```

I want to export to excel.

tried with the above code & excel is not downloading in ionic 6 angular 14 app.

anything missed here. Pls help us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error or status message you get when calling the `ExportToExcel()` method?

Comment: When i run this in browser excel is generated and downloaded. How ever when i create APK file and testing only code is executed and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried cheking the permissions of the android manifest file for writing and eading files?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```